# How to build a pdf vignette in R and RStudio

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown, vignette

I am new to writing R packages. I'm trying to learn how to make a vignette for my package. I have created a vignettes folder with a file "getting-started.Rmd"

```
---
title: "WaterML Tutorial"
author: "Jiri Kadlec"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Introduction to the WaterML R package}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

## Quick Start

This simple example shows how to get started with the <my R package>.
```

To build the vignette I use the command:

```
devtools::build_vignettes()
```

Then I run `Rcmd.exe INSTALL my_package`, and to view my vignette I run:

```
browseVignettes("my_package")
```

However I only see the vignettes in the html and source format:
[image: I don't see the pdf option for vignettes]

As you see in the screenshot, there's no "pdf" option. How do I configure my .Rmd file to create my vignette in the pdf format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936969/enforce-pdf-package-vignette-with-knitr or possibly try [output:pdf_document](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your header, you are telling R to output only an html vignette in line:

```
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
```

If you want pdf, try:

```
output: pdf_document
```

According to [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html#vignettes):

> Output: this tells rmarkdown which output formatter to use. There are many options that are useful for regular reports (including html, pdf, slideshows, …) but rmarkdown::html_vignette has been specifically designed to work well inside packages. See ?rmarkdown::html_vignette for more details.

So you might have a few small problems using a raw pdf.

At this time, rmarkdown does not have a `output: rmarkdown::pdf_vignette` option

Comment: And there is no need to have a `output: rmarkdown::pdf_vignette` option (`pdf_document` will simply work). The reason for `html_vignette` is explained here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/package_vignette_format.html

Comment: Good explanation. So I see that html_vignette is the preferred format in R packages because the size is much smaller.