# Why is my vignette html and not pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm confused as to why my R package's vignette is in HTML [on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=wCorr) and not a pdf.

I followed the advice at [Enforce PDF package vignette with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936969/enforce-pdf-package-vignette-with-knitr) and used

```
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
```

to generate the vignette, but there it is, a pdf. The full header of one of the files is

```
---
title: "wCorr Formulas"
author: "Paul Bailey, Ahmad Emad, Ting Zhang, Qingshu Xie"
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'
output:
  pdf_document: default
vignette: |
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{wCorr Formulas}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
---
```

you can see the whole package at https://github.com/cran/wCorr or, before it gets built at https://github.com/ahmademad/wCorr

Answer (score 3):

You are including copies of the HTML output (presumably from an earlier version) in `inst/doc`.

This might not have been intentional; I believe `devtools::build_vignettes` might do it to work around a bug in R:  https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17416.  But there are better workarounds, e.g. described here:  https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1540 .

Comment: those are added when building the package, they aren't present in the package when it gets built. I added a link in the OP to the package before it is built.

Comment: Nevertheless, you put them there.  Use the standard build tool (i.e. R CMD build) and you won't get them unless you ask for them.

Comment: I use "R CMD build" at the command line. I'd never used "devtools::build_vignettes" until you mentioned it here.

Comment: The version on CRAN is 1.9.1; the one on Github is 1.9.0.  When I build the one on Github I don't get the HTML files, but the CRAN one has them.  You should check the tarball that you sent to CRAN with 1.9.1 in it:  I suspect (for whatever reason) it contains the HTML files.

Comment: Yes, I suspect the same. I now think it is that I didn't have my environment setup correctly to build pdf files, so R CMD build didn't build them. Then, CRAN posted what I sent--which makes sense.